# Sencha Touch 2.x - How to load a custom view into a tab panel? Use xtype?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I am completely new to Sencha 2 Touch. This is my second day playing with it.

I have a custom class (app/view/Howdy.js):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Howdy', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'howdy', // <--- this creates the 'howdy' xtype reference right?
  requires: [
    'Ext.SegmentedButton'
  ],

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    html: ['Hello Word.'].join("")  
  }
});
```

and I am now trying to load it into a tab when clicked:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
   extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

   config: {
     fullscreen: true,
     tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

     items: [
        {
            title: 'TAB 1',
            iconCls: 'star',
            xtype: 'howdy', // <--- WHY IS THIS CRASHING MY APP?
        },
    ]
}
});
```

If I remove the xtype declaration inside TAB 1 and replace it with an html everything works fine. As soon as I try and load my custom view into the tab all I get is a white screen in my browser and console shows no errors ???

P.S Yes everything is setup correctly already in App.js:

```
views: ['Howdy','Main'],
```

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late to update this thread but the solution was simply to remove the *fullscreen: true* declaration from inside the config in **MyApp.view.Howdy**.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this will help you:
MyApp.view.Howdy

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Howdy', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  xtype: 'howdy',
  requires: [
    'Ext.SegmentedButton'
  ],

  config: {
    incoCls: 'star',
    title: 'TAB 1',

    html: ['Hello Word.'].join("")  
  }
});
```

MyApp.view.Main

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
   extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

   config: {
     fullscreen: true,
     tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

     items: [
        {xclass: 'MyApp.view.Howdy'},
    ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use alias: widget.XTYPE

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Howdy', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.howdy', // <--- this creates the 'howdy' xtype reference right?
  requires: [
    'Ext.SegmentedButton'
  ],

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    html: ['Hello Word.'].join("")  
  }
});
```

Comment: tried this. Still doesn't work and just presents a blank white screen. I believe since Sencha 2.x that defining xtype: 'xxxx' is the same defining alias: 'widget.xxxx' ? Think I just read that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.  First, xtype is what you use to define the type if you're adding it instantly...if you haven't already defined it with Ext.create.  If you've already created it, then you don't need it.  When creating panels, each item contains all the info for itself, title, icon, everything.  Then, just add the item(s) into a tabPanel:

```
var a = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
  iconCls:'star',
  title:'tab1',
  html:'tab one content'
});
var b = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
  iconCls:'star',
  title:'tab2',
  html:'tab two content'
});


var panel = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel',{
    items:[a,b]
});
```